Eclipse java Dynamic Reports Suddenly Failing
I've had dynamics reports net.sourceforge.dynamicreports running in my project for years. Something I have done has suddenly stopped it working. Some code that compiles properly makes any instance of classes that use dynamic reports from creating.
I pull out all the code for dynamic reports from the class and it works.
I've tried putting the code back in little bit by bit and found that some things that used to work like
FontBuilder basefont = stl.fontArial();
StyleBuilder boldStyle = stl.style().setFont(basefont).bold();
StyleBuilder boldCenteredStyle = stl.style(boldStyle).setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

will make the creation of the class this is in to fail with an invokation error.
If I modify the code I can get some things to work but if I try and create a column using code like
TextColumnBuilder<String> colTest = col.column("Help", type.stringType());

I cannot even create an instance of the class.
I have tried reverting to my old code but keep getting the same error at the same place.
I installed the latest version of Eclipse - no good.
I added the latest version of dynamic reports - no good
I tried adding jasper reports - no good
I grabbed my last github version of my project which was working but it no longer works.
Somehow I've broken my project.

(1) downgrade your JDK version (1.8 ?) (2) downgrade your
server version 2018 (3) downgrade your IDE Version.(Eclipse version to older version 2018).

Thanks for the suggestion life888888, but I had already tried that.

After a full day trying to solve this I finally managed to correct the project. The maven dependencies were not in the dployment assembly. Why Maven dependancies are not there by default I do not know, or maybe at some stage I removed them.
Right click the project, choose properties -> Deployment Assembly and add the Maven Dependencies.

That solved ot for me.
